# Get POST body and return it to the browser

Tags: java, sockets, http, post, proxy

I have implemented a proxy using sockets in Java.
Now I'm experiencing a problem with POST method, I mean, I'm able to capture the POST request, but I don't know how I have to proceed to capture the content (the body, not the headers) of this POST request, once done I would like to return the content to the browser (I need to implement this because when for example I try to login using my username and password it does nothing).

I capture the request using this code:

```
while ((buffer = in.readLine()) != null){
    System.out.println(buffer);
    headers[i] = buffer;
    i++;

    if(buffer.startsWith("GET")){
        String[] splitText = buffer.split(" ");
        url = splitText[1];
        post = false;
    }
    if(buffer.startsWith("POST")){
        String[] splitText = buffer.split(" ");
        url = splitText[1];
        post = true;
    }
    if(buffer.startsWith("Host:")){
        String[] splitText = buffer.split(" ");
        host = splitText[1];
    }

    if(buffer.isEmpty()){
        break;
    }
}
```

And I'm trying to return the body of the POST request using this code (obviously it's not working, only works for GET request):

```
URL u = new URL(url.toString());
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();

if(post){
    connection.setDoOutput(true);
    connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
}

byte[] buf = new byte[8196];
int bytesRead;
InputStream stream;
stream = connection.getInputStream();

while((bytesRead = stream.read(buf)) > 0){
    out.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
    out.flush();
}
```

Any help would be much appreciated.
Thanks.

Edit, complete code:

```
public void run() {

        try {


            BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(clientSocket.getInputStream()));
            BufferedOutputStream out = new BufferedOutputStream(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

            String host = null;
            String url = null;
            int i=0;
            String [] headers = new String [100];
            String buffer;
            boolean post = false;

            while ((buffer = in.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(buffer);
                headers[i]=buffer;
                i++;
                if(buffer.startsWith("GET"))
                {
                    String[] splitText = buffer.split(" ");
                    url = splitText[1];
                    post = false;
                    }
                if(buffer.startsWith("POST"))
                {
                    String[] splitText = buffer.split(" ");
                    url = splitText[1];
                    post = true;
                    }
                if(buffer.startsWith("PUT"))
                {
                    String[] splitText = buffer.split(" ");
                    url = splitText[1];
                    post = true;
                    }
                if(buffer.startsWith("Host:"))
                {
                    String[] splitText = buffer.split(" ");
                    host = splitText[1];
                    }

                if (buffer.isEmpty()) break;
                }



            if (!checkURL(host) && !checkWORD(url)){

                    URL u = new URL(url.toString());
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) u.openConnection();
                    if (post){
                        connection.setDoOutput(true);
                        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");

                    }


                    for (int x=1;x<i-1;x++){
                    if (!headers[x].contains("Accept-Encoding:")){
                        connection.setRequestProperty(headers[x].substring(0, headers[x].indexOf(":")).toString() , headers[x].replace(headers[x].substring(0, headers[x].indexOf(":") +2), "").toString());
                    }
                    }

                    boolean redirect = false;

                    int status = ((HttpURLConnection) connection).getResponseCode();
                    if (status != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                        if (status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_TEMP || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_MOVED_PERM || status == HttpURLConnection.HTTP_SEE_OTHER)
                        redirect = true;
                    }


                    if (redirect) {

                        String Url = connection.getHeaderField("Location");
                        URL urlloc = new URL(Url.toString());
                        connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlloc.openConnection();

                        if (checkWORD(Url)){

                            PrintWriter outt = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

                            outt.write("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n");
                            outt.write("Date: Fri, 31 Dec 1999 23:59:59 GMT\r\n");
                            outt.write("Server: Apache/0.8.4\r\n");
                            outt.write("Content-Type: text/html\r\n");
                            outt.write("Content-Length: 57\r\n");
                            outt.write("Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:59:59 GMT\r\n");
                            outt.write("Last-modified: Fri, 09 Aug 1996 14:21:40 GMT\r\n");
                            outt.write("\r\n");

                            outt.flush();
                            outt.close();

                        }

                        for (int x=1;x<i-1;x++){

                            if (!headers[x].contains("Accept-Encoding:")){
                                connection.setRequestProperty(headers[x].substring(0, headers[x].indexOf(":")).toString() , headers[x].replace(headers[x].substring(0, headers[x].indexOf(":") +2), "").toString());
                            }
                            }
                    }


                        byte[] buf = new byte[8196];
                        int bytesRead;
                        InputStream stream;
                        stream = connection.getInputStream();
                        while ((bytesRead = stream.read(buf)) > 0) {
                            out.write(buf, 0, bytesRead);
                            out.flush();
                        }


                        }else{


                            PrintWriter outt = new PrintWriter(clientSocket.getOutputStream());

                            outt.write("HTTP/1.0 200 OK\r\n");
                            outt.write("Date: Fri, 31 Dec 1999 23:59:59 GMT\r\n");
                            outt.write("Server: Apache/0.8.4\r\n");
                            outt.write("Content-Type: text/html\r\n");
                            outt.write("Content-Length: 57\r\n");
                            outt.write("Expires: Sat, 01 Jan 2000 00:59:59 GMT\r\n");
                            outt.write("Last-modified: Fri, 09 Aug 1996 14:21:40 GMT\r\n");
                            outt.write("\r\n");

                            outt.flush();
                            outt.close();
                            }

            out.close();
            in.close();
            clientSocket.close();


        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        } 
    }
```

Comment: Few things to mention: **1)** Your POST code isn't posting anything at the moment. You also need to set a content type for most POST requests for them to work. **2)** I do not see the line `connection.connect()`. Without that line, the request body isn't being transmitted, thus your POST request won't return a response. Should you have simply omitted those lines for sake of simplifying your example code, please add them back to show you are actually submitting a valid request.

Comment: You are also not taking into account the *length* of the post data. Simply reading from the source stream until no more bytes are available is not adequate. You MUST look at the HTTP headers you have received to see HOW to read the post data, and you MUST send your own HTTP headers describing the post data to the next receiver so it knows how to receive the post data you are sending to it. See [RFC 2616 Section 4.4 - Message Length](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2616#section-4.4) for details.

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your comments, anyway I'm still getting the same errors... I'm going to update the initial post to show you the complete code

Comment: By the way, answering to your questions, all the headers are been set automatically, including content type and the length of the post data.